# How to change order to process priority on top command?

Tags: linux, process, priority

I have the below output from `top` command. Where is the process priority of the processes?

```
Mem: 678048K used, 336240K free, 0K shrd, 4K buff, 523012K cached
CPU:  0.5% usr 26.1% sys  0.0% nic 72.9% idle  0.0% io  0.0% irq  0.4% sirq
Load average: 1.89 1.75 1.62 3/154 3595
  PID  PPID USER     STAT   VSZ %VSZ CPU %CPU COMMAND
 3794     1 root     R     1992  0.2   0 19.5 /usr/sbin/syslogd
  297     2 root     SW       0  0.0   0  4.0 [ocf_0]
  299     2 root     SW       0  0.0   1  0.5 [ocf_1]
 1152     1 root     S     4032  0.4   1  0.3 /usr/sbin/procrecovery_mgr
 1100     2 root     SW       0  0.0   1  0.2 [ubi_bgt0d]
 1330     2 root     DW       0  0.0   1  0.2 [pfe_ctrl_timer]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called the [nice value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_(Unix)), and is shown by default in some of the configurations of `top`. If it is not showing by default, you can do the following

1. Execute `top`
2. Press <kbd>f</kbd>
3. Navigate to the line beginning with `NI` and press <kbd>Space</kbd>
4. Press <kbd>q</kbd> to return to the main view.

This is documented in sections 3a and 3b of the manpages of `top`.

**Edit**:
@Kusalananda has pointed out that priority is not the same as the nice value. The OP should examine the definitions of both and choose the appropriate one to use for his purpose.

To access the **priority**, change the `NI` in step 3 to `PR`.

My `top` is showing both priority and nice value by default.

Comment: The priority is not the same as the nice value, and `top` can show both.

Comment: Tried to move to nice value as mentioned above, but it does not work [no navigation exists]. Is there any other way to check the process priority?

Comment: @Ravi If it shows "toggle with letter" instead of navigation, just press the corresponding letter to show the column you need.

Comment: Don't you mean to press `s` on the `NI` field, NOT `Space` on it? `s` sets it to sort by that field.

Comment: `Space` is toggling the visibility of the field and `s` is for sorting. One may need both depending on the situations.